# Instantiate namespaced javascript class

Tags: clojurescript

I want to use google maps api v3, and it needs me to instantiate `google.maps.LatLng`. Using `clojurescript` this is what I do:

```
(ns foocljs.core)

(LatLng. (.-maps js/google) 100 100)
```

I got an error `undefined is not a function`, this is the culprit:

```
new foocljs.core.LatLng(foocljs.core.google.maps, // ... another args
```

I'm guessing this is because the compiler think that `LatLng.` is clojure namespaced class. How to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using js/a.b.c.d is a bad practice and is likely to break in future versions of the compiler (because it is not a clojure compatible version of interop from what I know)

The good way would be:

```
(def LatLng (.. js/google -maps -LatLng))

(LatLng. 100 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, I can just do this:

```
(js/google.maps.LatLng. 100 100)
```