# Clojurescript: Create New Object from Namespace

Tags: clojurescript

I'm relatively new to ClojureScript and having never worked in a lisp-like language before, I must say that the documentation is rather... lacking.  I just want to transform the following JavaScript statement into ClojureScript:

```
var obj = new namespace1.namespace2.SomeObject();
```

I know that you can create new instances of an object in cljs by writing something like

```
(SomeObject.)
```

but trying

```
(def obj (namespace1/namespace2/SomeObject.))
```

didn't compile.  What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this answer, it is exactly the same question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23653459/1400662

Pasted here:

Using js/a.b.c.d is a bad practice and is likely to break in future versions of the compiler (because it is not a clojure compatible version of interop from what I know)

The good way would be:

```
(def LatLng (.. js/google -maps -LatLng))

(LatLng. 100 100)
```